# Can you connect different OSes using an ad-hoc network?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, macos

Is it possible to connect multiple different operating systems to the same ad-hoc network so that they can play games or file sharing or network connections like LAN chat or LAN connection?

will connecting 2 different OS be much harder to configure than same OS?

Comment: Both can be connected to the same network, if both have games that allow for them to connect on a network, then yes. A lot depends on the protocols being used in various applications as some are interchangeable, others are not. This question should be rephrased to be much more specific about a particular application or action (like file sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, network connections are built on standards that are, for the most part, agreed upon and supported by most OSes.

The more important function than the browser, are the applications you're going to be using. The applications must be compatible in order to interact.

Comment: will it be much harder to configure than same OS connected to each other?

Comment: No, the settings may not be in the same place, and I assume you're familiar with the OSes you want to network, but the settings should generally be the same.

Comment: im just used to windows, just wondered ...

Comment: I've only built an ad-hoc once using Windows, but I'm familiar with Ubuntu, and I have seen Mac do an ad-hoc but I have never configured an ad-hoc myself using either of the latter two.